# Hiveserver2: Failed to create/change scratchdir permissions to 777: Could not create FileClient

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I'm running a MapR Community Edition Hadoop cluster (M3).

Unfortunately, the HiveServer2 service crashes and, according the log file in `/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.13/logs/mapr/hive.log`, there's a problem with permissions on the scratch directory:

```
2015-02-24 21:21:08,187 WARN  [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:init(74)) - Failed to create/change scratchdir permissions to 777: Could not create FileClient java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
```

I checked the settings for the scratch directory using `hive -e 'set;' | grep scratch`:

```
hive.exec.scratchdir=/user/mapr/tmp/hive/
hive.scratch.dir.permission=700
```

I notice that `hive.scratch.dir.permission` is set to 700 and the error message suggests that it wants to change this to 777. However, according to the filesystem, `/mapr/my.cluster.com/user/mapr/tmp` has 777 permissions and belongs to the mapr user.

```
mapr@hadoop01:/mapr/my.cluster.com/user/mapr/tmp$ ls -al
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  3 mapr mapr  1 Feb 22 10:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 mapr mapr  3 Feb 24 08:40 ..
drwxrwxrwx 56 mapr mapr 54 Feb 23 10:20 hive
```

Judging by the filesystem permissions, I would expect the mapr user to do whatever it wants with this folder and so don't understand the error message.

I'm curious to know if anyone's seen this before and, if so, how did you fix it?

**Update:**

I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/mapr/hive/blob/branch-0.13-mapr/service/src/java/org/apache/hive/service/server/HiveServer2.java), and notice some relevant comments just prior to the warning:

```
// When impersonation is enabled, we need to have "777" permission on root scratchdir, because
// query specific scratch directories under root scratchdir are created by impersonated user and
// if permissions are not "777" the query fails with permission denied error.
```

I added set the following properties in hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
  <value>777</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hive/</value>
</property>
```

... and created the `/tmp/hive/` folder in HDFS with 777 permissions:

```
mapr@hadoop01:~$ hadoop fs -ls -d /tmp/hive
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          0 2015-02-27 08:38 /tmp/hive
```

Although this looked promising, I still got the same warning in `hive.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the permission of your /tmp/hive HDFS directory to set it to 777:

```
  hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

Or remove /tmp/hive ,  temporary files will  be created anyway even when you delete them.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /tmp/hive;  
rm -rf /tmp/hive
```

Comment: Thanks @Yosr. I appreciate the advice. The `/tmp/hive` directory didn't exist in HDFS (probably because MapR uses slightly different paths). I added it anyway and did a `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive`. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue.