# impala-shell query failing with Error(13)

Tags: shell, impala

I'm running an impala-shell on a 3-node cluster. Some queries work just fine, but a few return the following error:

```
Create file /tmp/impala-scratch/924abcb4827fd7ba:d15cd3585951f4b2_c8e0146a-37cd-457a-96f6-ac5d933cd4da failed with errno=13 description=Error(13): Permission denied
```

I have checked my local directory, and /tmp/impala-scratch does exist and it is read-write-executable by me. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. It turns out that the old /tmp/impala-scratch had access permissions:
drwxr-xr-x

According to: 
[Hiveserver2: Failed to create/change scratchdir permissions to 777: Could not create FileClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753538/hiveserver2-failed-to-create-change-scratchdir-permissions-to-777-could-not-cr)

You have to change the permissions to 777:

chmod -R 777 /tmp/impala-scratch/

And this fixed it.